# When I run roscore, it has the following error

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi:

When I use roscore command, it has the following error. Please help me.

```
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/b271445a-f9f2-11e0-ad43-485d607d0ff5/roslaunch-turtlebot8-4104.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 247, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/parent.py", line 254, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/parent.py", line 212, in _start_infrastructure
    self._start_server()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/parent.py", line 163, in _start_server
    self.server.start()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/server.py", line 371, in start
    code, msg, val = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(self.uri).get_pid()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1199, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1489, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1228, in request
    h = self.make_connection(host)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1305, in make_connection
    return httplib.HTTP(host)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 1020, in __init__
    self._setup(self._connection_class(host, port, strict))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 657, in __init__
    self._set_hostport(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 682, in _set_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: ''
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11587/when-i-run-roscore,-it-has-the-following-error./) by [HelenJiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1240/helenjiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get this error by setting your ROS_HOSTNAME or ROS_IP with a value including a colon.  The ROS_HOSTNAME or ROS_IP should not have a colon in it such as ROS_IP=192.168.1.1

For more information on environment variables see http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1